# How can I have a real /usr/bin in Cygwin instead of a dummy link to /bin?

Tags: ssh, cygwin

Today I wanted to install OpenSSH on my Cygwin (version 2.3.1) but noticed that OpenSSH binaries needed to be installed under `/usr/bin` and that Cygwin (for some reason) don't have a real `/usr/bin` directory, it's got `/usr/bin` only as a link (or alias whatever) to `/bin`. The same is true for `/usr/sbin` and it's a link to `/sbin`. The problem is, when I moved all ssh binaries to the `/bin` and try to run sshd or ssh-host-config which is used for configuring all binaries, it didn't work because ssh-host-config used `/usr/bin` for configuration and it's complicated to edit all config files for `/bin`

It would be perfect if I had a possibility to have a real `/usr/bin` in Cygwin. I've tried hopelessly to edit `/etc/fstab`  and put this line

```
none /usr/bin /usr/bin binary 0 0
```

in an attempt to make Cygwin see `/usr/bin`  as `/usr/bin` but no luck.

I'd like to have a real `/usr/bin` under Cygwin how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You mention that cygwin ,has "/usr/bin only as a link (or alias whatever) to /bin."- 
to be specific - use the "mount" command to observe /usr/bin appears to use "C:/cygwin64/bin"
e.g. "mount | grep /usr/bin" prints "C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.
There is a deep reason for having `/bin` as `/usr/bin`.

Instead check that in your path `/usr/bin` is before `/bin`; this will make happy openssh and some other programs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried that i.e. in par with the default Cygwin directory but OpenSSH still doesn't work. To clarify a bit here's the OpenSSH packages directory structure: http://i.hizliresim.com/YbJz3j.png
The trouble is that it uses /usr/bin inside all of its files too. It's ironic that this package is prepared by Cygwin. It's incompatible.

Comment: I know what is the package structure, but the mounting works fine for every one else. So what is your problem ?

Comment: Why are you using winzip for a cywin binary package ? The installation method uses setup that knows the mount of /`bin`

Comment: Well I prefer winzip because so I know exactly into which location the files are extracted and have more control over the installation. I have actually installed several apps this way, for instance pure-ftpd works fine. Now when I run ssh-host-config

`$ /bin/ssh-host-config
: No such file or directory 49: /usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh
: No such file or directory 53: cd: /bin
/bin/ssh-host-config: satır 75: unexpected syntax near \`$'{\r'' 
'bin/ssh-host-config: satır 75: \`update_services_file() {`

Comment: Now I'm trying the Cygwin setup's own extraction & installation tool to install OpenSSH. Soon I 'll write it out if it works or not.

Comment: cygcheck -l <package> will tell you where are all the files are installed if you used setup. If you bypass setup too many things can go wrong and all the postinstall script are not managed.

Comment: I guess you're right, because after I used the Cygwin setup to extract & install OpenSSH, it worked. That's slightly embarrassing for me .) But I guess everyone will appreciate the meaning of manual installation because it gives you total control on your system. However for this particular case, it was very likely my current Cygwin system was missing several necessary files and I couldn't spot them. Now it works.  You might like to edit your answer to include briefly this aspect of Cygwin?